# parameter not passing out of an input function

Tags: c

Consider the program:
...

```
/*
* UNDEE601W12A1p2.c
*
*  This program computes and prints the mass of a balloon of volume V in m^3, at a pressure of P.
*  in Pascals at a temperature T in K. The input data is read from the file datex.dat.
*
* Created on: Nov. 22, 2019
* Author: owner
*
*/
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int gas_prop_in(float P[100], float V[100], float T[100], int *numball);
float mass_calc_out(float P, float V, float T, float M);
int PVTM_out(float Pr[100], float Vo[100], float Te[100], int numball);

int main() {

    float Pressure[100], Volume[100], Temperature[100], Mass[100];
    int innum, inout;
    int numball;

    innum = gas_prop_in(Pressure, Volume, Temperature, &numball);

    printf("%f %f %f %d\n", Pressure[0], Volume[0], Temperature[0], numball);
    printf("%f %f %f %d\n", Pressure[1], Volume[1], Temperature[1], numball);
    printf("%f %f %f %d\n\n", Pressure[2], Volume[2], Temperature[2], numball);

    inout = PVTM_out(Pressure, Volume, Temperature, numball);

}


int gas_prop_in(float P[100], float V[100], float T[100], int *numball) {

    FILE *f_in;
    char file_name[20];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter name of a file you wish to see: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    f_in = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (f_in == NULL) {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(f_in, "%f\t %f\t %f\n", &P[i], &V[i], &T[i]) != EOF) i++;

    numball = i;

    printf("%d\n\n", i);
    printf("%d\n\n", numball);

    fclose(f_in);

    return 1;

}

float mass_calc(float P, float V, float T) {

    float M;

    M = P * V / (0.42 * (T + 460.0));

    return M;

}

int PVTM_out(float Pr[100], float Vo[100], float Te[100], int numball) {

    int i;
    float Ma[100];

    printf("%f %f %f %d\n", Pr[0], Vo[0], Te[0], numball);
    printf("%f %f %f %d\n", Pr[1], Vo[1], Te[1], numball);
    printf("%f %f %f %d\n\n", Pr[2], Vo[2], Te[2], numball);

    printf("PRESSURE (Pa)\t\t VOLUME (m^3)\t\t TEMPERATURE (K)\t MASS (kg)\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= numball-1; i++) {

        Ma[i] = mass_calc(Pr[i], Vo[i], Te[i]);

        printf("%8.2f\t\t %8.2f\t\t %8.2f\t\t %8.2f\n", Pr[i], Vo[i], Te[i], Ma[i]);

    }

    return 1;

}
```

...

I placed some print statements in to see if the variables were passing out of the input function gas_prop_in. The arrays passed out of the function just fine, but the integer numball, which has a value of 3 inside the function, does not.

The output of the program with printf statements are:

```
Enter name of a file you wish to see: datex.dat
3

3

202.449997 2.000000 285.089996 0
102.699997 0.500000 300.890015 0
225.889999 2.200000 295.000000 0

0
202.449997 2.000000 285.089996 0
102.699997 0.500000 300.890015 0
225.889999 2.200000 295.000000 0

PRESSURE (Pa)    VOLUME (m^3)    TEMPERATURE (K)         MASS (kg)
```

they show the value of numball is 3 within the gas_prop_in input function but becomes 0 when passed out of it (last value of tables above). The second table above was printed within the output function PVT_out. This is why the output function PVTM_out cannot produce the output table it is supposed to after the labels.

I haven't got a clue why the pointer isn't passing the value out.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `numball = i;` - if that doesn't generate a warning, you need to turn up your warnings and treat them as errors. That's assigning `int` to `int*`. That should be `*numball = i;`. The ensuing `printf` is in a similar predicament.

Comment: `while (fscanf(f_in, "%f\t %f\t %f\n", &P[i], &V[i], &T[i]) != EOF) i++;` should be `while (fscanf(f_in, "%f %f %f", &P[i], &V[i], &T[i]) == 3) i++;` (remove the specified `\t'` and `'\n'` -- they are covered by the `space` -- and the fact that `"%f"` ignores leading whitespace).

Comment: Instead of slinging multiple arrays around, why not a single array of a structure with the required fields?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It is working now. I have been away from C for a bit and am getting back into the proper use of pointers. I wil play with the structure idea. Thanks again.